# Upgrading SQLite database schema

Tags: android, sqlite

Presently I have my database code like this

```
public class AABDatabaseManager
{
    // the Activity or Application that is creating an object from this class.
    Context context;

    // a reference to the database used by this application/object
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    // These constants are specific to the database.  They should be 
    // changed to suit your needs.
    private final String DB_NAME = "database_name";
    private final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    // These constants are specific to the database table.  They should be
    // changed to suit your needs.
    private final String TABLE_NAME = "database_table";
    private final String TABLE_ROW_ID = "id";
    private final String TABLE_ROW_ONE = "table_row_one";
    private final String TABLE_ROW_TWO = "table_row_two";

    public AABDatabaseManager(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;

        // create or open the database
        CustomSQLiteOpenHelper helper = new CustomSQLiteOpenHelper(context);
        this.db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    }


    public void addRow(String rowStringOne, String rowStringTwo)
    {
        // this is a key value pair holder used by android's SQLite functions
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(TABLE_ROW_ONE, rowStringOne);
        values.put(TABLE_ROW_TWO, rowStringTwo);

        // ask the database object to insert the new data 
        try{db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);}
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void deleteRow(long rowID)
    {
        // ask the database manager to delete the row of given id
        try {db.delete(TABLE_NAME, TABLE_ROW_ID + "=" + rowID, null);}
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void updateRow(long rowID, String rowStringOne, String rowStringTwo)
    {
        // this is a key value pair holder used by android's SQLite functions
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(TABLE_ROW_ONE, rowStringOne);
        values.put(TABLE_ROW_TWO, rowStringTwo);

        // ask the database object to update the database row of given rowID
        try {db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, TABLE_ROW_ID + "=" + rowID, null);}
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("DB Error", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public ArrayList<Object> getRowAsArray(long rowID)
    {
        // create an array list to store data from the database row.
        // I would recommend creating a JavaBean compliant object 
        // to store this data instead.  That way you can ensure
        // data types are correct.
        ArrayList<Object> rowArray = new ArrayList<Object>();
        Cursor cursor;

        try
        {
            // this is a database call that creates a "cursor" object.
            // the cursor object store the information collected from the
            // database and is used to iterate through the data.
            cursor = db.query
            (
                    TABLE_NAME,
                    new String[] { TABLE_ROW_ID, TABLE_ROW_ONE, TABLE_ROW_TWO },
                    TABLE_ROW_ID + "=" + rowID,
                    null, null, null, null, null
            );

            // move the pointer to position zero in the cursor.
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            // if there is data available after the cursor's pointer, add
            // it to the ArrayList that will be returned by the method.
            if (!cursor.isAfterLast())
            {
                do
                {
                    rowArray.add(cursor.getLong(0));
                    rowArray.add(cursor.getString(1));
                    rowArray.add(cursor.getString(2));
                }
                while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            // let java know that you are through with the cursor.
            cursor.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // return the ArrayList containing the given row from the database.
        return rowArray;
    }



    public ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> getAllRowsAsArrays()
    {
        // create an ArrayList that will hold all of the data collected from
        // the database.
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> dataArrays = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();

        // this is a database call that creates a "cursor" object.
        // the cursor object store the information collected from the
        // database and is used to iterate through the data.
        Cursor cursor;

        try
        {
            // ask the database object to create the cursor.
            cursor = db.query(
                    TABLE_NAME,
                    new String[]{TABLE_ROW_ID, TABLE_ROW_ONE, TABLE_ROW_TWO},
                    null, null, null, null, null
            );

            // move the cursor's pointer to position zero.
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            // if there is data after the current cursor position, add it
            // to the ArrayList.
            if (!cursor.isAfterLast())
            {
                do
                {
                    ArrayList<Object> dataList = new ArrayList<Object>();

                    dataList.add(cursor.getLong(0));
                    dataList.add(cursor.getString(1));
                    dataList.add(cursor.getString(2));

                    dataArrays.add(dataList);
                }
                // move the cursor's pointer up one position.
                while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            Log.e("DB Error", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // return the ArrayList that holds the data collected from
        // the database.
        return dataArrays;
    }

    private class CustomSQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        public CustomSQLiteOpenHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            // This string is used to create the database.  It should
            // be changed to suit your needs.
            String newTableQueryString = "create table " +
                                        TABLE_NAME +
                                        " (" +
                                        TABLE_ROW_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement not null," +
                                        TABLE_ROW_ONE + " text," +
                                        TABLE_ROW_TWO + " text" +
                                        ");";
            // execute the query string to the database.
            db.execSQL(newTableQueryString);
        }
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
        {
            // NOTHING TO DO HERE. THIS IS THE ORIGINAL DATABASE VERSION.
            // OTHERWISE, YOU WOULD SPECIFIY HOW TO UPGRADE THE DATABASE.
        }
    }
}
```

Now i need to add other 3 columns to my table thus updating my database schema when I googled I found I need to call sqllitehelper constructor with new version number so I changed my code as below
but still its not calling onupgrade()

```
  public class AABDatabaseManager 
{
    // the Activity or Application that is creating an object from this class.
    Context context;

    // a reference to the database used by this application/object
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    // These constants are specific to the database.  They should be 
    // changed to suit your needs.
    static final String DB_NAME = "database_name";
    static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    // These constants are specific to the database table.  They should be
    // changed to suit your needs.
    private final String TABLE_NAME = "database_table";
    private final String TABLE_ROW_ID = "id";
    private final String TABLE_ROW_ONE = "table_row_one";
    private final String TABLE_ROW_TWO = "table_row_two";
    private final String TABLE_ROW_THREE = "table_row_three";
    private final String TABLE_ROW_FOUR = "table_row_four";
    private final String TABLE_ROW_FIVE= "table_row_five";
    public AABDatabaseManager(Context context)
    {
        //super(context, DB_NAME, null,2); 
        this.context = context;

        // create or open the database
        CustomSQLiteOpenHelper helper = new CustomSQLiteOpenHelper(context);
        this.db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void addRow(String rowStringOne, String rowStringTwo, String rowStringThree, String rowStringFour, String rowStringFive)
    {
        // this is a key value pair holder used by android's SQLite functions
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(TABLE_ROW_ONE, rowStringOne);
        values.put(TABLE_ROW_TWO, rowStringTwo);
        values.put(TABLE_ROW_THREE, rowStringThree);
        values.put(TABLE_ROW_FOUR, rowStringFour);
        values.put(TABLE_ROW_FIVE, rowStringFive);
        // ask the database object to insert the new data 
        try{db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);}
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void deleteRow(long rowID)
    {
        // ask the database manager to delete the row of given id
        try {db.delete(TABLE_NAME, TABLE_ROW_ID + "=" + rowID, null);}
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void updateRow(long rowID, String rowStringOne, String rowStringTwo,String rowStringThree, String rowStringFour,String rowStringFive)
    {
        // this is a key value pair holder used by android's SQLite functions
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(TABLE_ROW_ONE, rowStringOne);
        values.put(TABLE_ROW_TWO, rowStringTwo);
        values.put(TABLE_ROW_THREE, rowStringThree);
        values.put(TABLE_ROW_FOUR, rowStringFour);
        values.put(TABLE_ROW_FIVE, rowStringFive);


        // ask the database object to update the database row of given rowID
        try {db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, TABLE_ROW_ID + "=" + rowID, null);}
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("DB Error", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Object> getRowAsArray(long rowID)
    {
        // create an array list to store data from the database row.
        // I would recommend creating a JavaBean compliant object 
        // to store this data instead.  That way you can ensure
        // data types are correct.
        ArrayList<Object> rowArray = new ArrayList<Object>();
        Cursor cursor;

        try
        {
            // this is a database call that creates a "cursor" object.
            // the cursor object store the information collected from the
            // database and is used to iterate through the data.
            cursor = db.query
            (
                    TABLE_NAME,
                    new String[] { TABLE_ROW_ID, TABLE_ROW_ONE, TABLE_ROW_TWO,  TABLE_ROW_THREE,  TABLE_ROW_FOUR, TABLE_ROW_FIVE },
                    TABLE_ROW_ID + "=" + rowID,
                    null, null, null, null, null
            );

            // move the pointer to position zero in the cursor.
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            // if there is data available after the cursor's pointer, add
            // it to the ArrayList that will be returned by the method.
            if (!cursor.isAfterLast())
            {
                do
                {
                    rowArray.add(cursor.getLong(0));
                    rowArray.add(cursor.getString(1));
                    rowArray.add(cursor.getString(2));
                    rowArray.add(cursor.getString(3));
                    rowArray.add(cursor.getString(4));
                    rowArray.add(cursor.getString(5));
                }
                while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            // let java know that you are through with the cursor.
            cursor.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // return the ArrayList containing the given row from the database.
        return rowArray;
    }


    public ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> getAllRowsAsArrays()
    {
        // create an ArrayList that will hold all of the data collected from
        // the database.
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> dataArrays = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();

        // this is a database call that creates a "cursor" object.
        // the cursor object store the information collected from the
        // database and is used to iterate through the data.
        Cursor cursor;

        try
        {
            // ask the database object to create the cursor.
            cursor = db.query(
                    TABLE_NAME,
                    new String[]{TABLE_ROW_ID, TABLE_ROW_ONE, TABLE_ROW_TWO,  TABLE_ROW_THREE,  TABLE_ROW_FOUR, TABLE_ROW_FIVE},
                    null, null, null, null, null
            );

            // move the cursor's pointer to position zero.
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            // if there is data after the current cursor position, add it
            // to the ArrayList.
            if (!cursor.isAfterLast())
            {
                do
                {
                    ArrayList<Object> dataList = new ArrayList<Object>();

                    dataList.add(cursor.getLong(0));
                    dataList.add(cursor.getString(1));
                    dataList.add(cursor.getString(2));
                    dataList.add(cursor.getString(3));
                    dataList.add(cursor.getString(4));
                    dataList.add(cursor.getString(5));
                    dataArrays.add(dataList);
                }
                // move the cursor's pointer up one position.
                while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            Log.e("DB Error", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // return the ArrayList that holds the data collected from
        // the database.
        return dataArrays;
    }

    private class CustomSQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        public CustomSQLiteOpenHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context, DB_NAME,null, 2);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            // This string is used to create the database.  It should
            // be changed to suit your needs.
            String newTableQueryString = "create table " +
                                        TABLE_NAME +
                                        " (" +
                                        TABLE_ROW_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement not null," +
                                        TABLE_ROW_ONE + " text," +
                                        TABLE_ROW_TWO + " text," +
                                        TABLE_ROW_THREE + " text," +
                                        TABLE_ROW_FOUR + " text," +
                                        TABLE_ROW_FIVE+ " text" +
                                        ");";
            // execute the query string to the database.
            db.execSQL(newTableQueryString);
        }


        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
        {
            // NOTHING TO DO HERE. THIS IS THE ORIGINAL DATABASE VERSION.
            // OTHERWISE, YOU WOULD SPECIFIY HOW TO UPGRADE THE DATABASE.
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
             onCreate(db);
        }
    }

}
```

Please excuse for long question I thought it will help ppl to answer. so tell me what can be the problem why am unable to change my db structure.

Now when I run the code am getting error like unknown column table_row_three

and am invoking this from another service like this

```
 offlinedb= new AABDatabaseManager(this);

    offlinedb.addRow(longitude, latitude,imei,"check",date);
```

Comment: you're missing commas after your new rows: see your onCreate method

Comment: @M.Bennett I edited that now am getting can't create database when I check my log

Comment: In your call of the Superclass in your SQLLiteOpenHelper i would stick to using the DB_VERSION constant

Comment: ok then DB_VERSION =1, do I need to change it to 2? else onupgrade wont be called right?

Comment: yepp, change the constant value to 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Overlooked your instance call, you're definetely missing **getWritableDatabase()** before writing to the Database AND while we're at it, change your TABLE_ROW_ID contstant value to "_id" when working with cursors...should work now.

```
String newTableQueryString = "create table if not exists " +
                                    TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                                    TABLE_ROW_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement not null, " +
                                    TABLE_ROW_ONE + " text, " +
                                    TABLE_ROW_TWO + " text, " +
                                    TABLE_ROW_THREE + " text, " +
                                    TABLE_ROW_FOUR + " text, " +
                                    TABLE_ROW_FIVE + " text);";
```

That's how i would do it, since SQLite is bitchin we at least know you're in onCreate()

Comment: 08-22 09:32:26.862: E/error(11948): can't create database Am getting this error

Comment: try
        {
        offlinedb= new AABDatabaseManager(this);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
         Log.e("error","can't create database");
         e.printStackTrace();
        }

Comment: Thansk for the responses but I have used  getWritableDatabase() and I solved my problem as I increased my version number to 3 it got solved may be I messed up some things.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you have enought time to use a new framework, take a look here:

http://adaframework.com/

I heard about it in a conference and it looked very cool.

It manages the upgrading transparently...

I've to say that I have not test it yet, but it was very impresive seen to the guy in the conference making an managing a DB in android with that framework.

Answer (score 0):

When you have found you have no error's in code and every thing is working fine but still your database is not upgrading increase your version number it may help you. Thats what I did. hope it may help some other

Answer (score 0):

If there aren't any important data stored in the database already, I would suggest, that you delete your database, and set it up again. Because the database structure won't accept any changes after it is set up. So even if you solved a problem (for example, the missing comma, which lead to the column not found error, the problem won't be solved.) Because you changed the version of the database, it worked.

After you make changes in the database structure (not the methods) , reset you database or the version.

(set go DDMS View-> File Explorer ->  data ->  data -> your package name -> database )